# Cannibals & Missionaries in First Order Logic

Tags: first-order-logic

Consider the Cannibals & Missionaries Problem:

> In the missionaries and cannibals problem, three missionaries and
>   three cannibals must cross a river using a boat which can carry at
>   most two people, under the constraint that, for both banks, if there
>   are missionaries present on the bank, they cannot be outnumbered by
>   cannibals (if they were, the cannibals would eat the missionaries).
>   The boat cannot cross the river by itself with no people on board.

**How to model this problem in First Order Logic?**

I have been trying to model it for over 20 hours now, but I failed time again. Is there a resource available online or can someone help me?

Comment: Consider the state variables: number of missionaries on bank A, number of missionaries on bank B, number of cannibals on bank {A,B}, number of {missionaries,cannibals} in boat,bank which the boat is on.  Now, each of these is really a sequence of variables - you will have at (discrete) time `t` one copy of each of them.  Represent them as predicates in the logic, and you can easily translate each of your sentences above indicating a constraint into a statement in first order logic (with an appropriate number system and numeric operators such as increment and greater-than assumed, of course...)

Comment: We can use greater-than, but I don't think we introduced increments. What do you mean by "sequence of variables", "appropriate number system" ?

Comment: I mean that you'll need numbers as objects in your language, and that for example "cannibals in the boat" is really "cannibals in the boat at time t=1", "cannibals in the boat at time t=2", and so forth.   You can represent the entire series with a single predicate that takes a time argument..  You need to constrain the state at `t=(n+1)` given the state at `t=n`.   For example, you might have `Forall($t:Boat_At_Left[$t] <=> ~Boat_At_Left[$t+1])` to express the boat shuttling back and forth, etc...  note what "$t+1", (or `Sum[$t,1]`, with "1" a constant, if you prefer) means is assumed here...

Comment: Can you give me some sample FOL statements so that I can understand better?